# Repeat last frame in video using ffmpeg

Tags: video, ffmpeg

Hi i'm trying to concatenate few mp4 clips each of 2 secs length, created using drawtext filter, but before that I want to extend length of some of these by repeating the last frames.How can I do it?

Answer (score 43, accepted):

With a build of ffmpeg newer than 2nd Nov 2018, you can use the below command :

```
ffmpeg -i in.mp4 -vf tpad=stop_mode=clone:stop_duration=2 out.mp4
```

Audio is ignored. For older versions, see below

The overlay filter, by default, repeats the last frame of the overlay input over the base input if the former has ended but the latter hasn't. So, the key is to overlay a truncated version of the main video over the full-length stream, thus "extending" the last frame. There's a different and simpler way to do the above:

```
ffmpeg -i in.mp4 -filter_complex "[0]trim=0:N[hold];[0][hold]concat[extended];[extended][0]overlay" out.mp4
```

Where `N` is the duration of the extension, in seconds.

Comment: @vdegenne - my explanation covers the logic but not the mechanics of [filtergraph](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#Filtering-Introduction) which would be cumbersome to do each time. The name of the filters are self-explanatory as are the pad labels I've used.

Comment: @Gyan ok thanks. Could you just explain the purpose of `;[extended][0]overlay` ? because you concat [0] and the trimmed part [hold] already. What does the overlay do here ?

Comment: The trim is trimming the *first two* seconds of the video, but the OP wants to repeat the *last frame*. So the purpose of trim+concat is to extend the duration but with the wrong content. The overlay relies on the filter's behaviour to provide the right content.

Comment: I had to add `fifo` after the `trim` command, otherwise ffmpeg yelled `[Parsed_concat_5 @ 048f7760] Buffer queue overflow, dropping.` and extended the video only by 3 seconds regardless of the trim length. But be prepared to have a huge portion of RAM ready for this (I had to download a 64bit build of ffmpeg, because by 32bit could not allocate enough RAM).